# Flutter SharedPreferences value to Provider on applcation start

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to to set a value from sharedpreferences to provider at application start.

this what I have so far, sharedpreferences to widget is working:
https://gist.github.com/andraskende/a19c806aeef0ce88e9a9cafa49660ab4#file-main-dart-L211-L223

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your code, I just gave you an idea how you can do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally i figured out with trial and error... It can be done in the constructor as:

```
class BarcodeProvider with ChangeNotifier {

  BarcodeProvider() {
    setup();
  }

  void setup() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String url = (await prefs.getString('url') ?? '');
    _url = url;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  ......
}
```

Comment: so what triggers your setup() to be called?  Is the class BarcodeProvider() just always instantiated at the start of the app?

Answer (score 5):

```
// global variable, that can be accessed from anywhere
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs; 

void main() async { // make it async

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // mandatory when awaiting on main

  sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); // get the prefs
  // do whatever you need to do with it

  runApp(MyApp()); // rest of your app code
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to read a value from SharedPreferences at startup and insert that value into a provider...  But so far I can only change a provider value from inside a widget manually..  Thanks for the help !

Comment: The above code should get you there. You can read the value from sharedPrefs after it is initialised, create a public variable to assign this value to. And you can then use it in Provider

Comment: `Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.)`